# Android app wont run a second time

Tags: android, animation, crash

I have an Android app that shows a frame-by-frame animation activity. At the end of the animation it starts a background service and closes the activity. Here is the code:

```
    cont = getApplicationContext();

    final ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img);
    img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.intro);

    img.post(new Runnable() {           
        public void run() {
            animation = (AnimationDrawable)img.getBackground();
            animation.setOneShot(true);
            animation.start();
            timer = new Timer();
            timer.schedule(new timer_exp(), 3400);
        }
    });
}



class timer_exp extends TimerTask{
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //start service
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(cont, MainService.class);
        startService(serviceIntent);
        //kill activity
        finish();           
    }

}
```

When I run the app I can see the animation and then the service starts. When I press on the app's icon again, I get a black screen and the app crashes.

Any Ideas to what the problem might be?

Thanks,
PB

Comment: What is the output in LogCat? Any exception mentioned?

Comment: When I press the icon the second time I get nothing on the LogCat.

Comment: if it crashes, then you WILL get something in the LogCat. look again

Comment: I think it does not even start. I have some log messages in each method and there is nothing in the LogCat. There are no other messages when I try to start the app at the second time.

Comment: Which method are you running this code in? I assume that is is being called from something like onCreate, onStart or onResume?

Comment: I tried from OnCreate and from OnStart. Both got me the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some investigation, it turned out that the service was the problem.
I had some `Thread.sleep()` in several places that caused the UI thread to crash.
After adding another thread for these actions the problem solved.